# RecyclerView is not showing data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm currently trying to create a dynamic header with a recyclerView. I have written the ListAdapter aswell as the ViewHolder. The custom list elements are added, and also the numer of the elements within the list is correct, but somehow it's not showing the object data, but only the dummyText that was added at the layoutdesign.

HeaderlistAdapter:

```
class HeaderListAdapter(val context: Context, val headers: List<CustomHeader>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HeaderViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): HeaderViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.ui_basic_custom_list_element_header, parent, false)
    return HeaderViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return headers.size
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HeaderViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    holder?.bindHeader(headers[position])
}
fun setFocus(step:UIStep)
{
    for(header in headers)
        header.Active=header.MainContent==step
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
}
```

HeaderViewHolder:

```
class HeaderViewHolder:RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
@Bind(R.id.ui_adapter_main) var mainText:TextView?=null
@Bind(R.id.ui_adapter_additional) var additionalText:TextView?=null
@Bind(R.id.ui_adapter_layout) var layout:LinearLayout?=null


constructor(itemView: View): super(itemView){
    ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView)
}
fun bindHeader(header:CustomHeader){
    if(header.Active) {
        mainText?.text = header.MainContent.description
        additionalText?.text=header.AdditionalText
        layout?.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorBackgroundActive.toInt())
    }
    else{
        mainText?.text=header.MainContent.number.toString()
        additionalText?.text=""
        layout?.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorBackgroundInactive.toInt())
    }
  }
}
```

Here is, how the listAdapter looks within the view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ui_basic_lv_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorBackgroundInactive"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Below here you se the xml of the custom element

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/colorBackgroundInactive"
android:textColor="@color/colorHeaderFont"
android:id="@+id/ui_adapter_layout">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ui_adapter_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Main Info"
    android:textSize="36sp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ui_adapter_additional"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="additional"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Comment: please post your xml code

Comment: First of all make sure your views are binding correctly with your variables by debugging your app and if it's not binding properly then use findViewById method to bind views with your variables like `val mainText = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.ui_adapter_main) as TextView` in viewholder constructor and try again.

Comment: add your activity code

Comment: first of all change your recyclerview items layout height to wrap_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was something wrong with the

```
@Bind
```

I replaced that by using findViewById within the binHeader function:

```
fun bindHeader(header:CustomHeader){
    val mainText = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ui_adapter_main)
    val additionalText = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ui_adapter_additional)
    val layout = itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ui_adapter_layout)
    if(header.Active) {
        mainText?.text = header.MainContent.description
        additionalText?.text=header.AdditionalText
        layout?.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorBackgroundActive.toInt())
    }
    else{
        mainText?.text=header.MainContent.number.toString()
        additionalText?.text=""
        layout?.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorBackgroundInactive.toInt())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

contentList may be null ,if contentList is Null, the method following '?' will not execute . and after setting the adapter can not call notifyDataSetChanged ;

Comment: i know, but the contentList ist not null. Also there is added the correct number of elements to the list, but the text of the elements was never set.

Answer (score 0):

You should set layout manager for recyclerview

myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManagerVertical);